# EF Core 3 "UPDATE" SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, ef-core-3.1

I would like to write an EF Core 3 statement that corresponds to the following SQL statement:

```sql
UPDATE c 
SET c.Field = c.Field + 1 
WHERE c.UniqueProperty = some_value
```

It appears that EF Core does not allow me to *increment* the value of some field without reading it first - is this true?

Comment: EF Core is an ORM, not a data access library like ADO.NET (which it uses). It's meant to Map Objects to Relational tables/views, not as a replacement for SQL. It's meant to detect changes to an application's Objects and Map it to SQL statements that update the Relational tables

Comment: For this statement, it's easier to just write a parameterized ADO.NET query, or use a micro-ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) to make calling such code as easy as `connection.Execute("update .... where someField=@value",new {value=..."});`

Comment: The real question should be when to use an ORM and when not?

Comment: I see, so I gather there is absolutely no way to do this in EF Core? I prefer to avoid data access libraries (such as ADO.NET) and not to write raw SQL queries.

Comment: What do you think ORMs use? All of them use ADO.NET. What are you really trying to avoid? Writing the raw SQL? Why? Avoid SQL injections? That's what parameterized queries are for. Simplify the code? Use Dapper. Avoid long and complex queries in the code? You probably need stored procedures or views for this. A SQL Builder for modestly complex queries? There are some available, including some extensions for Dapper

Comment: True, but they hide that detail from me as a user!

Comment: You posted a question asking for that non-detail right now. A database is not an implementation detail, it's what remains in production when the application is replaced by a new one. You can get simplified access in several ways, but there's always going to be an impedance mismatch (that's an actual term) between object languages and set-based systems

Comment: ORMs allow me to swap my DB with any other DB I like. My question is simple: can I do this in EF Core or not? To which the answer seems to be no for now.

Comment: No, ADO.NET does that. You can write DB-agnostic code already. ORMs only do what the name says: Map Objects to Relational tables. And they don't do that very well, there are always problems. You just found one.  The answer to your question is *no never, it was never meant for this*

Comment: You should read [The Vietnam of Computer Science](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/). The problems with ORMs are known since the start. Objects simply aren't sets, and imperative languages are terrible at set-based coding. Or functional coding- SQL is quite close to functional programming

Comment: You should look at [F#'s SQLProvider](https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/). It's probably the query mechanism with the least amount of friction right now. Tables are exposed as types in the language, *at compile time*, without generating classes. This allows ensuring the queries work at compile time, something ORMs can't do. Any changes will be exposed in the table types and generate compilation errors instead of runtime errors after deployment

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments. p.s. not all orms use ADO.NET

Comment: Can you give one example? That would be a very bad situation for the ORM developer - they'd have to actually write providers for any supported database themselves instead of depending on the DB vendor's drivers.

Comment: Hibernate is one exmaple.

Comment: No, NHibernate uses ADO.NET too. Hibernate is a Java project, a completely different runtime. It still uses Java's standard data access API though.

Comment: It's quite possible for an ORM to use a completely different provider model, especially if it tries to access a non-relational database. EF Core works with Cosmos DB through Cosmos' SDK. For relational databases though, almost everyone tries to use standard APIs like ADO.NET, JDBC or lower level APIs like ODBC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for feature request [#795](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/795). Until then, you can do this:

```cs
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated(@$"
    UPDATE c 
    SET c.Field = c.Field + 1 
    WHERE c.UniqueProperty = {some_value};
");
```